# Strava heat mapping images returned from API

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

https://labs.strava.com/heatmap/#7.65/-75.95197/41.17804/blue/ride
Does anyone know how Strava have achieved this. By the looks of the network tab strava request overlay images using the API.

I have geo data, but how can I turn those geo data to heatmap images on a nodejs side ?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/stellaraccident/mapnik-rasterizers/ might help, but if your concerned about making raw data available to the client you should think about preprocessing the data.

Comment: @AndrewHarvey so this is a C++ library and how can I use this on my nodeJS server ?

Comment: https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is probably doing it in the frontend by loading a third-party map (such as Google Maps, which also has heatmaps capability) and then loading the heatmap layer with your data.

As for the way they are doing it, since it's such a specialized case, they're probably rendering the overlays on the server side and serving it as images, as you mentioned, which is also considerably harder to do than loading a map with data and letting it do it's thing.

Comment: yes, but the problem is I cannot send the data to the frontend for security reasons. If I send the data to the frontend then anyone could locate the places

Comment: this is why I need the heatmaps to be generated on the nodejs server

Comment: Well then you can either grind (/merge/aggregate) that data down to less granular "centers of mass" (or centers of heat, in this case) so that no exact locations are sent **OR** if you really want to go the server-side way maybe find an heatmap rendering module for node and go with that.